# How to match index vba

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, match

Im really beginner . I have to sheet. First i have column
This is header from input_4. Same Range columns A:E and same rows.

[image]

seconde ;

[image]

Example  input date its Arkusz2 its column A:E rows 100x

[image]

My code is on below. But i didn't get any error. But position on first sheet is still empty.

```
Sub Work_Click()

Dim x As Integer, y As Integer
Dim sourceRange As Range
Dim lookRange As Range
Dim Header_Range As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wsD = Sheets("Arkusz2")
Set wsVO = Sheets("input_4")
Set sourceRange = wsD.Range("A:E")
Set lookRange = wsD.Range("A:A")
Set Header_Range = wsD.Range("1:1")

wsVO.Select

MyLastRow = wsVO.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
MyLastColumns = wsVO.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For x = 2 To MyLastRow
For y = 2 To MyLastColumn

On Error Resume Next

wsVO.Cells(x, y) = WorksheetFunction.Index(sourceRange, _
WorksheetFunction.Match(wsVO.Cells(x, 1), lookRange, 0), _
WorksheetFunction.Match(wsVO.Cells(1, y), Header_Range, 0))

Next y
   Next x
On Error GoTo 0

MsgBox ("Done.")
End Sub
```

Comment: "I didn't get any error" - because you hid error(s) with `On Error Resume Next`. Remove that.

Comment: I remove all on error still nothing :(

Comment: Maybe replicate the INDEX/MATCH/MATCH in the worksheet first as a formula... should give you a clue as to what's not working.

Comment: Please give some example input/output data. See [mcve]. • Try going through your code step by step using F8 and investigate the variable values to narrow down your issue.

Comment: MyLastRow = wsVO.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
MyLastColumns = wsVO.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For x = 2 To MyLastRow
For y = 2 To MyLastColumn   Here is going to  Next x but nothing happend

Comment: It is very unclear what your screenshots show. Which imige is which sheet and which ranges in those sheets do they each show? Please give us more precise information.